# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null - leaflet

Tags: javascript, ajax, leaflet

I'm trying update my leaflet map via JS + AJAX, but leaflet return me an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null on leaflet.js:5

I have function, which get data from server, everything works, when I call function `getData`,  I get data and function `printRoute` writes data to "test" element, but `L.polyline([...` still returns error. Data ( output of `xhttp.responseText` ) are in right format, which `L.polyline` needs 
`( [ 49.999319, 13.897081 ], [ 49.997681, 13.905933 ], ... , [ 49.996141, 13.913901 ], [ 49.994664, 13.921527 ] )`

When I do it only on server, only with PHP, without AJAX, everything works fine.
Please, do you have some hints?

```
function getData( url, cFunction, postedData ) {
  var xhttp;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      cFunction( this );
    }
  };
  xhttp.open( "GET", url, true );
  xhttp.send();
}

function printRoute( xhttp ) {
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
  var route = L.polyline([ xhttp.responseText ], {color: 'red'} ).addTo(map);
}
```

Comment: ...and what's the value of `xhttp.responseText` during runtime? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that other people can run.

Comment: @IvanSanchez value of `xhttp.responseText` is LatLong coordinates:

[ 49.999319, 13.897081 ], [ 49.997681, 13.905933 ], ... , [ 49.996141, 13.913901 ], [ 49.994664, 13.921527 ]

Comment: maybe responseText is a string, try eval('[' + xhttp.responseText + ']')

Comment: Given that a string containing an array is basically JSON, I'd use `JSON.parse()` instead of `eval()`, for safety. Don't `eval()` random stuff, folks!

Comment: @luckyape this helps me. you should post your answer

Comment: @horoyoio thanks, note that IvanSanchez is correct regarding the use of eval

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates being past from the server are in array notation, however the `xhttp.responseText` property is actually a String type. The polyline function is looking for an array of arrays but gets past an array of a single string.

```
['[ 49.999319, 13.897081 ], [ 49.997681, 13.905933 ]']
```

instead of

```
[[ 49.999319, 13.897081 ], [ 49.997681, 13.905933 ]]
```

configure the server to return a proper json object to fix this.

using `eval('[' + xhttp.responseText + ']')` to convert your string into an array is not recomemeded as it creates a security vulnerabilitie in your code.