# Leaflet maps AJAX - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0'

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, leaflet

I keep getting the error:

```
leaflet.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at i._projectLatlngs (leaflet.js:5)
    at i._projectLatlngs (leaflet.js:5)
    at i._project (leaflet.js:5)
    at i._reset (leaflet.js:5)
    at i.onAdd (leaflet.js:5)
    at i._layerAdd (leaflet.js:5)
    at i.whenReady (leaflet.js:5)
    at i.addLayer (leaflet.js:5)
    at i.addTo (leaflet.js:5)
    at Object.success (scripts.js:267)
```

When trying to add a path to a leaflet map.

The idea is that I click on a flight path, retrieve the lat & long from a database and showing the route on the map.

I have [checked out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55680201/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-0-of-null-leaflet) which has pointed me in the right direction, but I still can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

The php page sends json data to the javascript and I have confirmed that the variable received is an array by using $.type()

Here is my php code:

```
foreach ($fp as $key => $value)
{
  if($value =="")
  {
    continue;
  }
  $sql = "SELECT latlong from fix where name = '$value';";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
  {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
      $latlong = $row['latlong'];
      $latlong = convertll($latlong);
      array_push($route,"[".$latlong."]");
    }
  }
}
echo json_encode($route);
```

The output I get when I run this page is:

`["[52.3991,-5.7566]","[52.2416,-5.6802]","[51.9947,-5.0402]","[51.7255,-3.2630]"]`

Each $value is a point on the route and then the database will give the lat & long of that point. The function convertll is to convert the coordinates to the correct format.

On the javascript side:

```
function showroutemap(id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/exercises/ajax/getFlightPlanRoute.php?q="+id,
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result)
    {
      var latlngs = result;
      console.log($.type(latlngs));
      console.log(latlngs);
      var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs, {color:'red'}).addTo(mymap);
    }
  });

}
```

console.log($.type(latlngs)) shows - `array`

console.log(latlngs) shows - `["[52.3991,-5.7566]", "[52.2416,-5.6802]", "[51.9947,-5.0402]", "[51.7255,-3.2630]"]`

From what I have seen the error is something to do with the way the JSON data is formatted but I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: A Leaflet `LatLng` must be an `Array` of two numbers, not a `String` containing the JSON representation of an `Array` of numbers. Remove those double quotes.

Comment: Just create the array in the correct format (without any custom made json like `"[".$latlong."]"`). Make sure `$latlong` is an array and not a comma separated string when you push it to the `$route` array. Now, you're pushing `[52.3991,-5.7566]` as a string.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks a million, in my php function I was returning $var1.",".$var2

I've changed it to an array and now it works ! Thanks a million !